# django api throwing 500(internal server) error with connection to mysql

Tags: django, python-2.7

I get 500(Internal Server Error) for the below code, cant able to identify the problem. Please help me

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .audfile import daywisedetail,hourwisedetail

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^pyapi/api/daywise/(?P<start_date>[\w-]+)/(?P<end_date>[\w-]+)/$',daywisedetail.as_view()),
url(r'^pyapi/api/hourwise/(?P<start_date_val>[\w-]+)/(?P<end_date_val>[\w-]+)/$',hourwisedetail.as_view()),
]
```

audfile.py

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View
from django.template.loader import get_template
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
import MySQLdb

sdatabase = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="password",db="main")

class daywisedetail(APIView):
    def get(self,request,start_date=None,end_date=None,format=None):
        db = sdatabase
        cursor = db.cursor()
        daydetail = """select id, values, name, email from day_users where date(reg_date) between '%s' and '%s' """ % (start_date,end_date)
        cursor.execute(daydetail)
        getdaydetailresult = cursor.fetchall()
        mainlist=[]
        for v0 in getdaydetailresult:
            for v1 in v0:
                mainlist.append(v1)
        data = {
                "hours": mainlist
        }
        return Response(data)

class hourwisedetail(APIView):
    def get(self,request,start_date_val=None,end_date_val=None,format=None):
        db = sdatabase
        cursor = db.cursor()
        hourwisedata = """select id, values, name, email from hour_users where date(reg_date) between '%s' and '%s' """ % (start_date_val,end_date_val)
        cursor.execute(hourwisedata)
        hourwisedataresult = cursor.fetchall()
        mainlist1=[]
        for v2 in hourwisedataresult:
            for v3 in v2:
                mainlist1.append(v3)
        data1 = {
                "days": mainlist1
        }
        return Response(data1)
```

If i have single class(daywisedetail), api is working properly, if i am adding second class(hourwisedetail), both the apis are showning 500 responce.

cant able to find where is the bug, please help me.

Comment: one question, why are you using custom cursor when Django has builtin support for database(MYSQL) and you can use it using ORM and Model

Comment: @Exprator: I dont know about it. can you please guide through the same. The same format i usually used in python2.7. so followed the same.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial02/